# What could be the reason Angular 5 + Material 2 are very very slow?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

I know this might not be a very good question. But I really don't know what to do and I am searching for reasons.

I am running my custom Angular 5 + Material 2 application locally and the `mat-dialog` and `mat-tab` are very slow. I have even tried to turn off animations but it's still very slow.

Also when compiling for production with `ng-build --prod` delivers very slow results.

So maybe I am doing something wrong regarding the dialog. Here is my code:

```
  openEditDialog(car:Car) {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditDemandComponent);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.id = car.id;
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The edit dialog was closed');
    });
  }
```

My constructor:

```
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient, 
    private dialog: MatDialog, etc..
```

and the constructor of the dialog component:

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditDemandComponent>, etc..
```

Inside the dialog component I am using the code `this.dialogRef.close();`

I am really out of options here and I really don't get it, since the material 2 docs are super fast and for me locally everything is super slow. Indicating slow as animations not going smoothly. Taking at least 2 seconds to open a dialog or switch tabs.

Here are my versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
```

**It's slow in Chrome, IE, and Edge**

My system is a development laptop, core I7, SSD, 16gb RAM etc. Don't think it's the system that is slow.

Can anyone help me?

**Edit:**
Added this browser performance measure: I think the issue is somewhere in the  animations. It's running a few, and only this one already takes 1.2 seconds. It would be acceptable if it was smooth, but it isn't. Nothing is really smooth regarding material actually. Just can't explain it.

Added also an image of all that it's doing. Is this normal?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since, this is related to performance, please mention your system's config.

Comment: Perhaps you're binding to a function somewhere in the view - instead of just to fields?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what do you mean exactly? Shouldn't you bind to functions anywhere? I am calling functions on button clicks, but that's about it.

Comment: @Mr_Green added my system config in the question. Don't think that's the problem though.

Comment: Event bindings are fine but `{{someCalculatedValue()}}` or `[foo]="someCalculatedValue()"` usually causes performance issues, because `someCalculatedValue()` will be called every time change detection runs.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am not doing that. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Did you check performance in development or production mode?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer both

Comment: Any information from the browser profiling tools where the time is spent?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer see my edit

Comment: Is this an animation of yours or from the material components?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer from the material components

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer also added an image that indicates that it is doing really a lot.

Comment: I'd try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com and create a bug report in the material components repo.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer see my edit 2. It's related to the `mat-table` I am using the components in

Comment: Try reproducing in http://stackblitz.com I can't tell from the information, I haven't used these material components at all yet myself.

Comment: I agree, the dialog really remain semi transparent and hangs in that state for couple of seconds.

Comment: I might be too late to the conversation but have you tried changing the ng-container to a div? We had to remove ng-containers in our code due to speed issues. Simply replacing ng-containers with divs made our code orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @eddierunner haven't tried. Will do

Comment: Material Design CSS (Material2) is not lightweight as Bootstrap and other UI frameworks. It looks much beautiful but the performance is not too good. I am personally not satisfied with the performance.

Comment: How about turning off animation? they are sugar coating but rarely necessary. I usually turn off lots of them by overriding CSS properties

Comment: @Spock Using Material design is also not really necessary, but it looks nice and the UX is great, same for animations. I should not have to turn off anything manually, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have now figured out that it is related to the big mat-table that has about 300 records that actually contains the buttons to open these material dialogs. When I have only two records it's as fast as the angular documentation. I still can't really understand it, since I would expect this to work (300 is not that much.), but it answers the question. **The reason this is slow is because of larger tables in combination with dialogs.**

Code:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxFlex="96px"> </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxFlex="96px">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="openEditDialog(element)"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="openDeleteDialog(element)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

**Unfortunately the fix was not using this at all (in this way).**

Comment: I have the same problem. Using a large table with data freezes the app occasionally which is very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with a table becoming very slow after 10 rows of data or so.
Turns out, the table gets very slow if you use things like dialogs, selects, menus, and other generated controls within a table row.  Material Menus can be moved outside the table by using `matMenuTriggerData` to pass the data to a single menu outside of the table.  Dialogs can be used by triggering a function that creates the dialog.  Selects do not have a good alternative that I found, so I ended up restyling a Material Menu that lived outside of the table.

The table is very quick with hundreds of rows now.